# How to Send the Alert changes to External Email Addresses

Tags: alert, sharepoint-email, notifications

I don't have any Email server ,I have SharePoint 2016 I want to send all changes in sharepoint to All Users
 I want To send Notification To external Email like Hotmail,Yahoo,gmail...
How to Configured it?

Answer (score 0):

Look at article, create [Simple Mail Transfer Protocol for SharePoint](https://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-blog/configuring-an-smtp-server-for-sharepoint/)

Comment: I dont Have SMTP Server I want To send Notification To external Email like Hotmail,Yahoo,gmail...

Comment: You can't, it is by design, https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d9b669dc-ad2b-4e6c-aaa6-b3dae26f4ac4/mails-are-not-sending-if-the-recipients-are-non-sharepoint-users-in-online-sharepoint-by-using-rest?forum=onlineservicessharepoint